# Java 8 does not render currency symbol

Tags: java, locale, currency, symbols

I found one strange situation in Java 8. I'm going to format number to specific locale and some of them doesn't work correctly.

```
long tenMillion = 10000000L; // this is ten million
Locale[] locales = Locale.getAvailableLocales();
//Locale[] locales = NumberFormat.getAvailableLocales(); // the same situation
for (Locale locale : locales) {
String currency = "Ten million in " + locale.getDisplayName() + "  is " +
                NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(locale).format(tenMillion);
    if (locale.getDisplayName().equals("Ukrainian")){
        System.out.println(currency);
        System.out.println(Currency.getInstance("UAH").getSymbol(locale));
    }
}
```

output

```
Ten million in Ukrainian  is ¤ 10 000 000,00
UAH
```

But when I create the instance of this locate I have correct results:

```
Locale uaLoc = new Locale("uk", "UA");
String currency = "Ten million in " + uaLoc.getDisplayName() + "  is " +
        NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(uaLoc).format(tenMillion);
System.out.println(currency);
System.out.println(Currency.getInstance("UAH").getSymbol(uaLoc));
```

output

```
Ten million in Ukrainian (Ukraine)  is 10 000 000 грн.
грн.
```

It's true not just for Ukrainian locale and for other:

```
Ten million in Bulgarian  is ¤ 10 000 000,00
Ten million in Italian  is ¤ 10.000.000,00
Ten million in Korean  is ¤ 10,000,000.00
Ten million in Latvian  is ¤ 10 000 000,00
etc.
```

But locales with countries formats correctly:

```
Ten million in Bulgarian (Bulgaria)  is лв.10 000 000
Ten million in Italian (Italy)  is € 10.000.000,00
Ten million in Italian (Switzerland)  is SFr. 10'000'000.00
Ten million in Korean (South Korea)  is ￦10,000,000
Ten million in Latvian (Latvia)  is 10 000 000 €
```

Looks like Currency connected only to country. And that very correct way!

Does anyone know how to request API changes for Java 9?
Would be great to have follow API

```
Locale.getAvailableCountryLocales();
```

to avoid any misunderstanding.

Thanks

Comment: Well, if you only input the language, there is no specific information about the country, right? For instance, if you select English as a language, the monetary display will be different depending on whether the country is, for instance, USA or UK... While I'm not sure of it, my guess here is that only when a country is specified in addition to a language is the locale implementation capable of displaying the correct currency representation. Same would go for French depending on whether the country is France or Canada, for instance.

Comment: I wonder what `uaLoc` in your first code snippet is ...

Comment: `¤` is the [Unicode Character 'CURRENCY SIGN'](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/a4/index.htm).

Comment: @Tom thank you for review. That was "locale". Edited

Comment: @zapl thanks, that's new info for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your actual question: 
Here is an overview of the process: http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/1
You'll basically need to fill in a form and email it (the address is included in the article) and hope enough people have the same request as you. (I don't know if it will meet the 'two weeks of engineering work' requirement.

If you're up to it, you can also participate as JCP Public, allowing you to comment and discuss existing proposals, or even add new ones if you become a JCP member by signing the Java Specification Participation Agreement (More info: see link to JSPA-pdf following the next url).

Start here: https://jcp.org/en/participation/overview

Comment: Thank you for useful links, will try to pick up this topic.

Answer (score 1):

I found one tricky way how to get all available locales with countries only. Into java 8 was added new static method filter

```
filter(List<LanguageRange> priorityList,Collection<Locale> locales)
```

This method is a part of realization RFC 4647

```
List<Locale.LanguageRange> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
list1.add(new Locale.LanguageRange("*-*"));
// Locales
List<Locale> list3 = Locale.filter(list1,Arrays.asList(Locale.getAvailableLocales()));
list3.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Output:

```
ar_AE
ar_JO
ar_SY
hr_HR
fr_BE
es_PA
mt_MT
es_VE
zh_TW
da_DK
es_PR
vi_VN
en_US
etc.
```

It's not the best way, but it is something.

Answer (score 0):

`Locale.getAvailableLocales()` returns a List of Locales, which either

- only specify the language, but no country
- or specify language and country.

Example:

```
it, : Italian
it, CH: Italian (Switzerland)
it, IT: Italian (Italy)
```

In my installation I see two ucrainian locales, one corresponding to `Locale("uk")` and one to `Locale("uk", "UA")`.

In general every language-only locale is accompanied with one or moe language+country locales.

If you change your condition to

```
 if (locale.getDisplayName().startsWith("Ukrainian")){
```

you will also see the two ucrainian entries, and one displays the result you want.

Comment: yes, I've already understand it during writing question in stackoverflow. In addition would be great to have new api method that will return all locales with specified countries only.

Comment: @Garbachov yes, the Locale API is not optimal, would be great if you could file a request to improve the lookup of Locales.

Comment: `Locale.getISOCountries()` will get the country codes and `new Locale("", "UA", "")` will suffice.